# Data for Dynamic Columns

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I have the following problem: I have an xml with 3 levels of nodes as source for a rtf file. I am able to build a table with dynamic columns but only for 1 key into the first column, second row. For the second column I split into months of year columns and on the second row I am able to put the data. But, when I have 3 keys in the first column for which I want to bring data, I am not able to do this. 
Context:

```
<?for-each-group:U_REGISTROIVA;A.JRNL_TYPE?>
```

Table:

```
`
Cell(2,1) = ?for-each-group:current-group();./A.VAT_TXN_TYPE_CD?>
?variable@incontext:G1;current-group()?>?A.VAT_TXN_TYPE_CD?>
?xdofx:if A.VAT_RECOVERY_PCT=0 then '' else '  IN'||' 
'||A.VAT_RECOVERY_PCT||'%  ' end if?> 
?A.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT?>

Cell(1,2) = ?for-each-group@column:/U_REGISTROIVA/U_REGISTROIVA2;./A.MONTH?>
?sort:current-group()/A.MONTH;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
?xdoxslt:month_name(A.MONTH, 0, $_XDOLOCALE)?>?end for-each-group?>

 Cell(2,2) = ?for-each-group@cell://U_REGISTROIVA2;./A.MONTH?>
 ?sort:current-group()/A.MONTH;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
 ?($G1[(./A.MONTH=current()/A.MONTH)]/A.TAX_BASIS_AMT_BSE)?>
 ?end for-each-group?>?A.TAX_BASIS_AMT_BSE?>?A.TAX_AMT_GROSS_BSE?>
 `
```

and final context:

```
<?end for-each-group?>
```

This works for me but now I have to put sums for each: (A.VAT_TXN_TYPE_CD,A.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT,A.VAT_RECOVERY_PCT) and I don't know how to put the variable @incontext:G1 relate to those key-fields.

Comment: Could you share your template and xml ? You can upload a zip file to https://transfer.sh/ and share the link.

Comment: I've already solved. It was from the structure of xml. I've created a compound key of three and put it in the structure of xml and I've flatten the xml and now is working fine. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Now I have another problem - I have some missed xml tags for some months and don't know how to do in order to keep 0 on cells where the info are missed.

Comment: Here you have xml and rtf: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e24c0bae802b236a7276398f32aee97720180824100021/b75595)